# How to use blocks inside twig child template where it doesn't extend the base layout?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to understand how I may use block tags inside a child template that is being included to another html file that is extending the base template.

In *index.html*, *nav.html* is being included, and in the *nav.html* I've included a block tag with a javascript for the menu, but it doesn't get passed to the *base.html*

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% block head%}{% endblock %}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block header %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**indexhtml**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Homepage{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include "nav.html" %} //here I am including the nav.html

    Nav is above here

{% endblock %}


{% block footer %}
    This is the footer block
{% endblock %}
```

**nav.html**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Homepage</li>
            <li>User account</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

{% block footer %}
    <script src="/js/dropdownmenu.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Included templates can't alter the blocks of their includer

Comment: @DarkBee, suggestions? I don't want to have to include the same js file over and over in the file that's extending the base template.

Comment: The "best" way I found i using the [deferred](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred#user-content-advanced-example) block extension. It delays the render of a block. If you follow the advanced example in my link you can see how you could solve it

Comment: @DarkBee, it would seem like that's the best and only option so far. Thanks for that, I'm not keen on installing extensions, but with this issue there's no way around it as I can see, and I read through all of twigs documentation. Yet again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially include another twig-template that extends your template with the blocks:

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

Comment: I see. But why doesn't OP not include the javascript in the index.html? He is including nav here always anyway. Including it in index does not introduce unused dependencies, so what is the problem then? I suggest not to 'cheat' the twig-engine for things that are not necessary to be cheated on :P

Comment: Because that can be frustrating. Imagine if you have like 10 javascript files, one for each controller you have. Adding them to your base would mean you have 9 HTTP's requests that you don't need. Other than that, there could be functions in the files that are named the same, but need to other actions based on the controller your are in e.g. `validateForm`

Comment: Exactly as @DarkBee described Jeroen.

Comment: So don't add them to the base, add them to index

Answer (score 0):

In child templates you cannot have HTML outside block, you need to move HTML code in nav.html inside some block